# Command phpunit -v gives me require_once error... what's wrong with my PEAR?

Tags: php, phpunit, pear

As per title, running `phpunit -v` on a fresh PHPUnit PEAR installation gives me a `require_once` failed error. Here is some additional information, i hope that anyone can help me with this.

```
Warning: require_once(File/Iterator/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\WAMP\PEAR\pear\PHPUnit\Autoload.php on line 45

Call Stack:
    0.0005     326744   1. {main}() C:\WAMP\PEAR\phpunit:0
    0.0011     369184   2. require('C:\WAMP\PEAR\pear\PHPUnit\Autoload.php') C:\WAMP\PEAR\phpunit:43


Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'File/Iterator/Autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\WAMP\PEAR;C:\WAMP\PEAR\pear\PHPUnit') in C:\WAMP\PEAR\pear\PHPUnit\Autoload.php on line 45

Call Stack:
    0.0005     326744   1. {main}() C:\WAMP\PEAR\phpunit:0
    0.0011     369184   2. require('C:\WAMP\PEAR\pear\PHPUnit\Autoload.php') C:\WAMP\PEAR\phpunit:43



    php -v

PHP 5.3.14 (cli) (built: Jun 13 2012 18:51:28) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans

`pear version`:

PEAR Version: 1.9.4
PHP Version: 5.3.14
Zend Engine Version: 2.3.0
Running on: Windows NT MARCO-PC 6.1 build 7601 (Windows 7 Home Premium Edition Service Pack 1) i586

    pear config-get php_dir

C:\WAMP\PEAR\pear

    echo %path% (only relevant paths)
C:\WAMP\PHP;C:\WAMP\PEAR;

    echo %PHP_PEAR_BIN_DIR%
C:\WAMP\PEAR

    echo %PHP_PEAR_DATA_DIR%
C:\WAMP\PEAR\data

    echo %PHP_PEAR_DOC_DIR%
C:\WAMP\PEAR\docs

    echo %PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR%

C:\WAMP\PEAR\pear

    echo %PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN%

C:\WAMP\PHP\php.exe

    echo %PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR%

C:\WAMP\PEAR

    echo %PHP_PEAR_TEST_DIR%

C:\WAMP\PEAR\tests

    pear list -c pear.phpunit.de

    INSTALLED PACKAGES, CHANNEL PEAR.PHPUNIT.DE:
    ============================================
    PACKAGE            VERSION STATE
    File_Iterator      1.3.1   stable
    PHPUnit            3.6.12  stable
    PHPUnit_MockObject 1.1.1   stable
    PHP_CodeCoverage   1.1.3   stable
    PHP_Invoker        1.1.0   stable
    PHP_Timer          1.0.2   stable
    PHP_TokenStream    1.1.3   stable
    Text_Template      1.1.1   stable
```

Comment: Obvious enough.. the `File/Iterator/Autoload.php` file is not present.

Comment: @MarcB how this is possible? I installed PHPUnit as suggested...

Comment: Just because phpunit is installed doesn't mean everything it depends on is.

Comment: Can you show `pear list` output.

Comment: @Gremo Sorry, I realized I wanted to see `pear list -a` or `pear list -c pear.phpunit.de`. (PHPUnit is in its own "pear channel"). Anyway, see my answer.

Comment: @MarcB it was not so obvious at the end, since i have alread File_Iterator installed. See my updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Check Dependencies

If you recently upgraded to PHPUnit 3.6, there's a possibility you still have an older version of File_Iterator installed and that's the problem (Based on a vague memory of the same error).

You can check the versions of installed packages with:

```
pear list -c pear.phpunit.de
```

If anything looks  not-right, or just to be sure upgrade PHPUnit to ensure it's at the latest version and so are all dependencies:

```
$ pear update-channels
$ pear upgrade phpunit/PHPUnit
Did not download optional dependencies: phpunit/PHP_Invoker, use --alldeps to download automatically
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use package "phpunit/PHP_Invoker" (version >= 1.1.0)
phpunit/PHPUnit_MockObject can optionally use PHP extension "soap"
downloading PHPUnit-3.6.12.tgz ...
Starting to download PHPUnit-3.6.12.tgz (119,220 bytes)
..........................done: 119,220 bytes
downloading File_Iterator-1.3.1.tgz ...
Starting to download File_Iterator-1.3.1.tgz (5,157 bytes)
...done: 5,157 bytes
downloading PHP_CodeCoverage-1.1.3.tgz ...
Starting to download PHP_CodeCoverage-1.1.3.tgz (132,726 bytes)
...done: 132,726 bytes
downloading PHPUnit_MockObject-1.1.1.tgz ...
Starting to download PHPUnit_MockObject-1.1.1.tgz (19,897 bytes)
...done: 19,897 bytes
downloading PHP_TokenStream-1.1.3.tgz ...
Starting to download PHP_TokenStream-1.1.3.tgz (9,860 bytes)
...done: 9,860 bytes
upgrade ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/File_Iterator-1.3.1
upgrade ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit_MockObject-1.1.1
upgrade ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHP_TokenStream-1.1.3
upgrade ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHP_CodeCoverage-1.1.3
upgrade ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit-3.6.12
$ phpunit -v
PHPUnit 3.6.12 by Sebastian Bergmann.
```

### Check include path

if you have the appropriate version of File_Iterator (and other dependencies) installed and `File/Iterator/Autoload.php` is missing - it's not installed anywhere that php is looking for it. Use `pear list-files phpunit/File_Iterator` to see exactly where pear thinks the file is - and verify that the file exists.

If it does then the pear root is not in your path, add it and you're good to go.

Comment: Problem (as you can see in the answer) is that phpunit is 3.6.12 and File_Iterator 1.3.1, exactly like yours. But for me it's not working.

Comment: C:\WAMP\PEAR\pear\File\Iterator\Autoload.php is present. As per documentation http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.checking.php#installation.checking.cli.modifyingphpini php.ini should then point to the main pear folder (that is C:\WAMP\PEAR).

Comment: with that you should have `C:\WAMP\PEAR\pear` in your include path. Alternatively: do _any_ pear packages work? It sounds like PHPUnit is simply the first thing on the cli you're using with pear dependencies.

Comment: You made my day man. It's like you said: C:\WAMP\PEAR\pear and NOT C:\WAMP\PEAR. Thank you so much for pointing me to it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Run `pear list -c pear.phpunit.de` to see what you have installed.

You should see output something like this:

```
Installed packages, channel pear.phpunit.de:
============================================
Package            Version State
File_Iterator      1.3.1   stable
PHPUnit            3.6.11  stable
PHPUnit_MockObject 1.1.1   stable
PHP_CodeCoverage   1.1.2   stable
PHP_Timer          1.0.2   stable
PHP_TokenStream    1.1.3   stable
Text_Template      1.1.1   stable
```

You're probably missing the first one (at least). You could go through and install each dependepency, but the easier way is `pear install -a pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit`. The `-a` means get all dependencies, and it works even when you already have PHPUnit installed. After running it on the above system it upgraded PHPUnit to 3.6.12 and also added PHP_Invoker which it seems I was missing.

```
Installed packages, channel pear.phpunit.de:
============================================
Package            Version State
File_Iterator      1.3.1   stable
PHPUnit            3.6.12  stable
PHPUnit_MockObject 1.1.1   stable
PHP_CodeCoverage   1.1.3   stable
PHP_Invoker        1.1.0   stable
PHP_Timer          1.0.2   stable
PHP_TokenStream    1.1.3   stable
Text_Template      1.1.1   stable
```

NOTE: The `-a` flags also gets optional dependencies. If you are a minimalist that may bother you :-)

Comment: According to `pear list -c pear.phpunit.de` i already have `File_Iterator`! So, what's wrong?

Comment: Did you try the `pear install -a pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit` command (as root)? If nothing needs to be updated, it will do nothing. Maybe you have a version mismatch.

Comment: Thank for your time. I found the error in AD7six answer. It was the pear include path.